# Issue with Prettyprint for HTML code with <pre> and/or <code>

Tags: jquery, html, pre, pretty-print

I'm trying to build an HTML element library (similar to Twitter Bootstrap) and I'd like to have a live version of the element next to the proper code markup for easy reference.

[**HERE'S THE LIVE PAGE FOR REFERENCE**](http://jonathonmoore.com/work/theme-library/)

I'm trying to use [**Prettify**](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to display something like `<button>Button</button>`, but I'm having two problems:

1. It seems to be adding random line breaks.
2. It's only numbering the first line and then stopping.

**Here's what I'm seeing when I view the page:**

[image]

**Question:** What am I doing wrong here?

**Here's the relevant HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Common HTML Library</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="prettify/prettify.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Button Section -->

    <h1>Buttons</h1>
    <p>Buttons should be used whenever something requires a clickable action which will result in a redirect, or dialog dismissal. Buttons appear in various states which are illustrated below.</p>

    <div class="live-example">
        <div class="element">
            <label for="defaultButton">Default Button</label>
            <button id="defaultButton">Button</button>
        </div>

        <div class="element">
            <label for="primaryButton">Primary Button</label>
            <button id="primaryButton" class="primary">Primary</button>
        </div>

        <div class="element">
            <label for="disabledButton">Disabled Button</label>
            <button id="disabledButton" disabled="disabled">Disabled</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="markup">
        <button>Button</button>
        <button class="primary">Button</button>
        <button disabled="disabled">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">prettyPrint();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here's the script.js file:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.markup').wrapInner('<pre class="prettyprint linenums" />');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.prettyprint').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/[<>\"\'\t\n]/g, function(m) { return {
      '<' : '&lt;',
      '>' : '&gt;',
      "'" : '&#39;',
      '"' : '&quot;',
      '\t': '  ',
      '\n': '<br/>' // needed for IE
    }[m]});
  });
  prettyPrint();
});
```

It seems like something is happening when it replaces all of the <> with the Unicode equivalents...like it's ditching the line breaks and/or adding in new ones. **What is going on here and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was occurring when the jQuery was sweeping through and replacing the tag carets with the equivalent Unicodes.

Here is my solution. I decided to add the markup blocks on the fly, so you'll see that I'm adding a div after each live-example block, filling it with the code from the live example **as text, not as HTML (this was the trick to getting it to work)**, then wrapping that in a `<pre>` tag.

```
// Add a markup block after each live example container
$('.live-example').after("<div class='markup'></div>");

// Fill the markup block with the code from the live container
$('.live-example').each(function () {
    $(this).next($('.markup')).text($(this).html());
});

// Wrap the code in the markup block with a <pre> tag for prettyprinting
$('.markup').wrapInner('<pre class="prettyprint linenums" />');
```

I'm still getting the odd `<br>` before and after my code, but I can deal with that.

**Result:**

[image]